# Linking multiple radio buttons with same name in different divs

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button

Currently I have multiple radio buttons in different divs. All radio buttons have the same name and selecting one should deselect any other. Somehow the radiobuttons are only linked within their column. How do I fix this?

```
<div class="form-group">

<!-- links -->
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Afvallen</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="goal" value="goal-min-15"> -15% (Aanbevolen)
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="goal" value="goal-min-20"> -20% (Agressief)
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="goal" value="goal-min-25"> -25% (Extreem)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- midden -->
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Op gewicht blijven</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="goal" value="goal-0"> +/- 0% (Standaard)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- rechts -->
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Aankomen</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="goal" value="goal-plus-5"> +5% (Voorzichtig)
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="goal" value="goal-plus-10"> +10% (Standaard)
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="goal" value="goal-plus-15"> +15% (Agressief)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey I tried this code in fiddle, it is working also (selecting one is deselect any other)

Comment: Actually the radio inputs _are_ linked. It is the `btn-group` code that isn't removing the active class from the buttons. http://www.bootply.com/q5HxXR6VVg

Comment: using <fieldset> instead of <div> can also solve the problem

Comment: @Turnip you are right, looks like I need a fix for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `.goal` class to each label and some jQuery did the trick

```
$('.goal').click(function(){
  $('.goal').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```